# Computational Puzzle Involving Primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Suppose $p$ is prime. Given an integer $x$ with $0 < x < p$, say $x$ is reversible from $i$ to $y$ precisely when $p - 1 - x = (p \times i - 1) \pmod y$.

Some examples with $p=7$:

$1$ is not reversible from $-9$

$6$ is reversible from $-5$ to any of the $y$ in $\{1,2,3,4,6\}$

$5$ is reversible from $-7$ to the unique $y$ in $\{3\}$

Now say $x$ is "**special**" exactly when there is an arbitrarily long sequence $y_0, y_1, y_2,...$ where $x$ is reversible from $0$ to $y_0$ and each $y_i$ is reversible from $-(i+1)$ to $y_{i+1}$.

My question: given a prime $p$, is there more than one such special $x$?

Comment: Actually , as it for the first time ,you have to know that here experts from diverse fields of mathematics look at your question , may be they can be much more knowledgeable than the OP , so instead of giving examples you can straight away make definitions and shoot out the question .However take care that the question has all its details explained well .

Comment: @ShivamPatel i really don't think there is any problem if the OP gives examples. **"...have to know that here experts from diverse fields of mathematics..."** sounds *really* arrogant.